Error "\runscript.tlu:918: command failed with exit code 1" running arara
When I run even a simple document like this:
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}

I got this error:
Process started (PID=7924) >>>
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.List.removeFirst()Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.islandoftex.arara.core.dependencies.Graph.kahn(Graph.kt:62)
    at org.islandoftex.arara.core.session.LinearExecutor.execute(LinearExecutor.kt:68)
    at org.islandoftex.arara.cli.CLI.run(CLI.kt:334)
    at com.github.ajalt.clikt.parsers.Parser.parse(Parser.kt:306)
    at com.github.ajalt.clikt.parsers.Parser.parse(Parser.kt:40)
    at com.github.ajalt.clikt.core.CliktCommand.parse(CliktCommand.kt:458)
    at com.github.ajalt.clikt.core.CliktCommand.parse$default(CliktCommand.kt:455)
    at com.github.ajalt.clikt.core.CliktCommand.main(CliktCommand.kt:475)
    at com.github.ajalt.clikt.core.CliktCommand.main(CliktCommand.kt:482)
    at org.islandoftex.arara.cli.CLIKt.main(CLI.kt:382)
C:\texlive\2024\bin\windows\runscript.tlu:918: command failed with exit code 1:
java.exe -jar c:\texlive\2024\texmf-dist\scripts\arara\arara.jar prova
<<< Process finished (PID=7924). (Exit code 1)
================ READY ===============

It worked until recently.
I'm on Windows 11, my TeXLive distribution is up-to-date, arara version: 7.1.4.
I have already restarted the pc and tried with different editors.

I've only found the removeFirst() method in Java 21. Which Java do you have installed?

Which version are you running? This error was found in 7.1.4, we sent a fix to CTAN, so hopefully version 7.1.5 should be fine...

For reference: https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/arara/-/issues/124 I just ran a TL update and got 7.1.5. When you have some time, could you try updating arara and see if the issue is solved, please? Thank you!

@PauloCereda on my machine it is working again after the update.

@PauloCereda After updating again this afternoon, it works. Maybe Italian mirror was late (I also updated this morning).

@Ronald Paulo solved the problem, thank you.

@UlrikeFischer Paulo solved the problem, thank you.

Unfortunately, version 7.1.4 of arara has indeed this issue. Depending on the JVM vendor and version, it can be reproduced.
The technical explanation of what triggered this issue can be seen here. We fixed it in version 7.1.5, so updating your local TeX Live installation will do the trick. :)
